# How to compare lenses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lenses

I am curious about Eq instance for lenses.
Lenses are functions. It is hard to compare arbitrary functions, but lenses are special class of functions.

I am thinking about using QuickCheck Arbitrary instances for `s` type:

```
lensesAreEqual :: 
  (Arbitrary a, Eq a) => 
  Lens' s a -> 
  Lens' s a -> 
  Gen Bool
lensesAreEqual l1 l2 = 
  and <$> forM [0..100] $ \_ -> do
    s <- arbitrary
    pure $ s ^. l1 == s ^.l2
```

I can hind lensesAreEqual monad behind unsafePerformIO for a neat Eq instance.

Does anybody know better solution?

Comment: You could just as easily do this for any function. It might work in a pragmatic sense, to figure out if 2 functions "seem to be equal" or not. But I'd be very reluctant to use this in pure code with UnsafePerformIO. It would be at least theoretically possible for this to tell you that the same 2 functions are equal in some runs but not in others!

Comment: There's not a sound way to do this in general. Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I want to generalize shim for scrolling multiple list widgets in brick based app and carry lens inside Name for picking specific list from app state in an event handler. Name should have Ord instance.

Comment: Since lenses are just functions, what if you defunctionalized what you were storing?

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this. Instead, define a real data type with the usual `Eq`uality, together with an interpretation function:

```
data ItemType = Weapons | Armor | Potions deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data AppState a = AppState
    { _weapons :: [a]
    , _armor :: [a]
    , _potions :: [a]
    , _activeType :: ItemType
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

toLens :: ItemType -> Lens (AppState a) (AppState b) [a] [b]
toLens Weapons = weapons
toLens Armor = armor
toLens Potions = potions
```

(This is what was meant in the comments about "defunctionalization".)